# SPFx can't use JQuery?

Tags: jquery, typescript, sharepoint, yo, spfx

I'm working on a brand new SharePoint Web Part using SPFx created by Yeoman, the scaffolding template is fine, adding the NPMs for JQuery and JQueryUI also get not a single problem, I see **GULP SERVE** running in the background without any errors.

The problem happens when I add the following line inside my JQWebPart.ts:

```
      import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
```

Once the line above is added the **GULP SERVE** outputs a very long list of errors, below are the last lines from all the errors:

```
[16:54:06] Error - typescript - node_modules\@types\jquery\index.d.ts(7502,33): error TS2314: Generic type 'Callbacks<T, Function>' requires 2 type argument(s).
[16:54:06] Error - typescript - node_modules\@types\jquery\index.d.ts(7503,36): error TS2314: Generic type 'Deferred<TR, TJ, any, TN>' requires 4 type argument(s).
[16:54:06] Error - typescript - node_modules\@types\jquery\index.d.ts(7504,41): error TS2314: Generic type 'Event<TTarget, EventTarget, TData>' requires 3 type argument(s).
[16:54:06] Error - typescript - node_modules\@types\jquery\index.d.ts(7505,36): error TS2314: Generic type 'Deferred<TR, TJ, any, TN>' requires 4 type argument(s).
[16:54:06] Error - typescript - node_modules\@types\jquery\index.d.ts(7506,37): error TS2314: Generic type 'AjaxSettings<TContext, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
[16:54:06] Error - typescript - node_modules\@types\jquery\index.d.ts(7510,28): error TS2314: Generic type 'jqXHR<TResolve, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
[16:54:06] Error - typescript - node_modules\@types\jquery\index.d.ts(7511,35): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<TR, TJ, any, TN>' requires 4 type argument(s).
[16:54:06] Error - typescript - node_modules\@types\jquery\index.d.ts(7517,32): error TS2314: Generic type 'PlainObject<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).
[16:54:06] Finished subtask 'tslint' after 3.95 s
[16:54:06] Error - 'typescript' sub task errored after 3.95 s
 "TypeScript error(s) occurred."
```

I have no idea what is going on with my Web Part when I try to use JQuery, does any body have any ideas???

Comment: Refer this link. This will solve your problem - https://thechriskent.com/tag/sharepoint-framework/

Comment: sir! that really solved my problem, i'm going ahead and paste that solution here, it might come handy later!

Comment: Thats Great ::))

Comment: thanks for your help, that solved my problem, can we close this thread? it seems i cannot mark your comment as answer or my own answer as such.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as correct. However you will not get any reputation for that. But you can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to user Rohit Waghela, there is a solution already in place to solve issues related to JQuery in SPFx:

https://thechriskent.com/tag/sharepoint-framework/

The problem is incompatibility between TypeScript and JQuery, so the bottom line here is the following:

1) remove JQuery:    `npm uninstall @types/jquery`

2) install compatible version:   `npm install @types/jquery@2.0.48 --save-dev`